# How do I get the answer to the random flash-card by clicking the panel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, random

I am trying to make a random flash card type of generator for javascript syntax. When i hit the random question button, it will display a random question such as "What is a variable?" but on clicking the panel, it should display the answer out of the answer array. All of the answers are in an object. I am 3 months new to programming, so any advice is appreciated.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  var ranQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random()* arrOfQuestions.length);
  $('#panel').html(arrOfQuestions[ranQuestion]);

  //produce answer in the panel html onclick
  $('#panel').on('click', function(){
    var pan = $('#panel').html();
    if(pan === arrOfQuestions){
       $('#panel').html(test);
    }
   })
})
```

[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/gatehrdy/pen/GQYogj)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using an array of objects to store your Q&A data

```
var questions = [
  {
     question: 'What is a variable?',
     answer: 'A variable is a container...'
  },
  {
    question: 'Function',
    answer: 'etc etc'
  }
];

//produce a random flashcard question from the arrOfQuestions array

$('button').on('click', function() {
  var ranQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length);
  $('#panel').html(questions[ranQuestion].question);

  //produce answer in the panel html onclick
  $('#panel').on('click', function(){
    var pan = $('#panel').html();
    if(pan === questions[ranQuestion].question){
       $('#panel').html(questions[ranQuestion].answer);
    }
   })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty much get there. Please try this out.

```js
var cards = {
  varQuestion: 'a variable is a container for a type of value',
  fun: 'A function runs a block of code when it is called',
  cond: 'a conditional statement runs a block of code if something is true, and can run another block of code if not.'
}


var arrOfQuestions = [[ 'varQuestion', 'What is a Variable' ],
                      [ 'fun', "What is a function" ],
                      [ 'cond', "What is a conditional statement" ]];

//produce a random flashcard question from the arrOfQuestions array

$('button').on('click', function(){
  var ranQuestion = Math.floor(Math.random()* arrOfQuestions.length);
  $('#panel').html(arrOfQuestions[ranQuestion][1]);
  
  //produce answer in the panel html onclick
  $('#panel').on('click', function(){
    $('#panel').html(cards[arrOfQuestions[ranQuestion][0]]);
   })
})
```

```css
.w3-col{
  height:300px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left:34%;
}
img{
  height:300px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<title>javascript flash cards</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<div class="w3-container w3-center">
  <h3>javascript flash cards</h3>
  <p>choose a random flash-card, then click the panel for the answer. <button>Click for Random Question</button>
    </p>
  
</div>
<br>
 
<div class="w3-row-padding">
    <div class="w3-col s4 w3-yellow w3-padding-32" id='panel'>
      <img src="https://scontent.felp1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-9/12645111_1075109299208404_1425810696977443472_n.jpg?oh=9067c4ea98ee0335a2bbd9e0f50eccfa&oe=5B4DF254" style="width:100%">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```